# Cartridge loading in Rodec phono stage

Tags: preamp, electronic-load

I saw a very strange design of phono stage in Rodec MX180 consoles. 3 generations of those mixers (mk1, mk2 and mk3) have this phono preamp on board!

They have an input filter with 1nF cap then 220 pF cap - the total input capacitance is 1220 pF, that's really a lot. Is it a mistake in the design? I made LTspice simulation with a cartridge model and the response is definitely not flat. Usually input capacitance in phono stages is like around 100-300 pF, sometimes they don't use input capacitors at all! My question is - am i missing something. If not then how it's possible they produced a lot of this gear without noticing?

[image: schematic]

[image: frequency response]

Comment: It's not 1220pF,  you forgot the 2.2uF capacitor. Show the simulation circuit, also. Anyway, what's the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Consider L1 and C35: 158uH and 1nF.

If 1uH and 1uF, the resonant frequency is 1,000,000 radians/second or 159,000Hz.

This circuit is 1,000X dmaller cap and 158x larger inductor, so Fresonant is about 300KHz, seemingly for RF (Am, TV, police/taxi, FM) signal rejection.

Then you have R5 and C15: 2.2Kohm and 220pF. With 1K ohm and 1nF being
1uF time constant, or 159,000H, this RC lowpass is about 300,000 Hertz.

So seems like the system/circuit person had some vendetta with energy above
300,000Hz.

The 2.2uF is in series, so not an overt shunting capacitance.

Why are these caps not a problem. They are after all in parallel with 47Kohm.

Assume 1nF in parallel with 100,000Ohm. That is a 100uS time constant, or 1.6KHz F3dB. The 1nF and 47K is 3.2KHz. But this ignores the source impedance in the cartridge. If that is low enough, the 1.22nF is not a problem.

========================

cubix wonders about resonance with the cartridge ---- perhaps one Henry?

I did not worry about that, presuming the MIXBOARD ENGINEER and the SOUND ENGINEER would select cartridges suitable for the Zin.

The "right cartridge" will become part of the folklore for this brand of mixboards.

Comment: I think you didn't consider that this circuit also resonates with a magnetic phono cartridge.